# Entity Framework 4: Self referencing entities, parent/child

Tags: entity-framework-4

we are using a model first design.

When I create a self referencing parent child association on an entity the designer always marks one end "many", which would be the "children" and is ok like that.
But the designer makes the other end "1 (One)", which is not ok since a parent is not required. If I change it to "0..1 (Zero or One)" the designer changes the other end from "* Many" to "0..1 (Zero or One)". So both ends are "0..1 (Zero or One)".
This is driving me crazy :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the 'ParentKey' column marked as nullable (Both in DB & EDMX)? Could prevent the relationship type you are after from being set up.

Comment: This is half of the solution. I had to change this directly in the EDMX file (open with XML editor). I also had to change the <Association> in the EDMX manually to Multiplicity="0..1". As long as you don't make any changes to the involved navigation properties it works.